# Retrieving object properties from the result fetched from mongodb in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to retrieve array of objects properties but I cannot retrieve any properties apart from _id in the object. But I can retrieve the whole array at once or even the individual objects inside array but not the properties that are within each object.

This is the JSON structure

```
[{
   "_id": "5a82df96f2730d4bb177ffe1",
   "project_id": 123,
   "project_name": "proj11",
   "tasks": [],
   "links": [],
   "__v": 0,
   "upsert": true
}]
```

This the code

```
taskDelay(req,res) {
    ProjectMaster.find({ "project_id": 123 })
    .then(response => {
        var result = response[0];
        var resultId = response[0]._id;
        var resultName = response[0].project_name;
        var resultProjId = response[0].project_id;
        console.log(result);           // outputs the object
        console.log(resultId);         // outputs 5a82df96f2730d4bb177ffe1
        console.log(resultName);       // undefined
        console.log(resultProjId);     // undefined
        res.status(200).send(response)
    })
    .catch(error => res
        .status(400)
        .send(error));
}
```

What might be the cause for showing undefined for other properties??

Comment: can u give the output of  `console.log(response[0])` ?

Comment: `{
   "_id": "5a82df96f2730d4bb177ffe1",
   "project_id": 123,
   "project_name": "proj11",
   "tasks": [],
   "links": [],
   "__v": 0,
   "upsert": true
}` It's outputting the first object as expected

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your ProjectMaster schema (or post it here) ?

Comment: `const ProjectMasterSchema=new Schema({},{strict: false});`  This is the project master schema

Comment: Looking your code and comments I cant find a reason for this to happend. I suggest you change `var` to `let` and run again to see what happens

Comment: Tried with `let` but getting  same the undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution for this issue. It is with the data format mongodb sending in response. I tried to do JSON.parse but it didn't work. `toObject()` did the trick.

```
taskDelay(req,res) {
ProjectMaster.find({ "project_id": 123 })
.then(response => {
    var result = response[0];
    var resultId = response[0]._id;
    var resultName = response[0].toObject().project_name;
    var resultProjId = response[0].toObject().project_id;
    console.log(result);           // outputs the object
    console.log(resultId);         // outputs 5a82df96f2730d4bb177ffe1
    console.log(resultName);       // outputs 123
    console.log(resultProjId);     // outputs proj11
    res.status(200).send(response)
})
.catch(error => res
    .status(400)
    .send(error));
}
```

I did a mistake of not reading mongoose document completely! This behaviour is regarding with mongoose data formats.